# How to read variables from txt file?

Tags: swift, xcode, file, filesystems

For example i've got a build archive and i want it to read some variables from txt file. So the question is there any way to upload a txt file to iPhone device and how to read that variables?

In my project i've got this constants:

```
baseURL: String = "someUrl"
client_id: String
client_secret: String
authorize_uri: String
token_uri: String
scope: String
redirect_uris: [String]
secret_in_body: Bool
```

and for example i created a txt file with this strings and somehow uploaded it to my device

i want the builded project to read this file

Comment: Add a file to your main bundle or use UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new plist file in your project, then parse it into a dictionary at startup. Once there you can just refer to each value by its key

If you create an extension to Bundle()

```
extension Bundle {
func parsePlist(ofName name: String) -> [String: String]? {

    // check if plist data available
    guard let plistURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "plist"),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: plistURL)
        else {
            return nil
    }

    // parse plist into [String: Anyobject]
    guard let plistDictionary = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: String] else {
        return nil
    }

    return plistDictionary
}
```

}

then you can load it into a dictionary like this

```
var dict = Bundle().parsePlist(ofName: "plistName")!
```

Xcode does a nice job of allowing you to edit the plist, and it'll be automatically included in your build